# Microsoft Dynamics CRM Slow Performance for Some Users

Tags: performance, dynamics-crm

We have a problem in Microsoft Dynamics 2016. CRM performance is very well but for some users it is awful.

For example saving an email generally take 0.5 seonds but for these users it takes 10 seconds or over!

We have disabled all customization, changed client system, check network, etc but problem is exist.

We monitor CRM processes by fiddler and more delay is in **ServerBeginResponse**.

Please help me to solve this problem.

thanks

Comment: This is likely too big of a set of reasons for the slow performance to solve here, but I'd check if these users are in a different business unit or have different security roles as that can affect the types of SQL Queries that are generated.  You didn't say if this is online or OnPrem, but if OnPrem, you may be able to address with generic SQL Tuning and addressing key missing indexes.

Comment: I create a user in CRM with same business unit and security roles and I didn't see any problem. But those users still have problem.This is On-premise.What SQL Tuning must set?What indexes might missing?

Comment: @Aramis2800 - for on-prem don't speculate - turn on SQL server profiler & watch for the queries being made when this guy tries to perform his action - you should be able to infer the problematic queries from the time SQL server is spending on resolving those. CRM uses row-level security - some checks are by-passed for system admins & generally sytem admins enjoys improved performance because on SQL level they don't have to go via those checks.

Comment: Unfortunately SQL Profiler not show any slowing in queries.Duration for queries (RPC:Completed) is under 1 seconds but duration for Audit Logout is over 1 seconds. My slow problem is obvious on save email. but insert into query related to save email has normal speed.In other hand queries are same for all users and if a query is slow all users must see it but only one user faced to slow problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I resolved this problem by Create Job For Delete **UserEntityUISettingsBase** Table Content And Problem Completely Solved.